# `[react/jsx-max-props-per-line]` eslint rule, compound settings

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'm looking at adding `[react/jsx-max-props-per-line]` to my config based on a request from the devs and I'm trying to find out...

Is there a way to have a rule that applies on `when: multiline` and another on `when: always`?

I'm wanting a `maximum` of five when we are within the `always` and a max of `one` on the multiline.

Answer (score 2):

No there is currently no way to use the rule the way you want. This feature request is being tracked in the following issue:

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2735

But for your specific case you can try using [`prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier). It enforces maximum 1 prop per line in case of multi-line tags. And with its [`printWidth`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) property you may get similar effect to around 5 props.